# How to display a powerpoint in a wpf application?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office

I want to make something simple : display a powerpoint in a wpf application. How can i do that? I read several ways on internet but i failed...

Thx

Comment: Any attempt that you can show...

Comment: I tried Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint and webbrowser view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JODConverter project

http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter

Uses OpenOffice as a conversion server.  It's written in Java, but it's fairly simple to do the same thing with C#.  Alternatively, you could call it as a command-line program.

Using it, you could convert the PPT to a series of images.  If you need to play PowerPoint animations or do anything that can't be just shown as an image, then this won't work.

Comment: Yes, i used image but it will be nicer to use a real powerpoint viewer.